# Joining multiple tables in Talend

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, talend

I have 5 tables (in MySQL) that I need to make inner joins and left joins between them in Talend. Can I do this using one tMap component? If not what is the best solution for this?

Comment: What did googling your title & 'sql' with & without 'stackoverflow' give you? What have you tried? What is some code you want to query in?

Comment: I have five tables let call them Table 1 to Table 5 and here is how I need to join them: 

Table 1 <inner join> Table 2 <inner join> Table 3 <left join> Table 4 <left join>  Table 5
I thought it's easier to tmap or tjoin to implement the aforementioned joins but seems it's easier if I write a Query in MySQLInput component that joins these three table. However, I noticed that this approach significantly slows down Talend designing view. Each time I want to make any changes to this component Talend freezes for almost 10 seconds (thinking mode). I need to extract 10 attributes from  each table

Comment: Please edit everything relevant to answering your question into your question, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without seeing more specific details,  it is possible.

Depending on your actual tables, number of columns, keys for joining, quantity of data, etc,  it could determine whether using a single tMap for all the look-ups would be appropriate.

If you want to post more details here about table definitions,  desired joins, quantity of rows, etc,  you can get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do all the joins in one tMap only